# Creating a 'blank' Bitmap in Portable Accord.Net

Tags: c#, portable-class-library, accord.net

I'm trying to create a blank Bitmap object in the Portable Accord.Net/Aforge.Net library (https://github.com/cureos/aforge), but I'm having trouble as the constructors don't get exposed, and I can't find another object to cast from.

I just want to create a bitmap of size x*y with a solid colour.

The only way I've figured out how to do it so far is to clone the bitmap, and then apply a filter to it to fill the whole bitmap with the same colour.

```
CanvasFill filter = new CanvasFill(new Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height), Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0));
filter.ApplyInPlace(img);
```

Surely there has to be a better way?

Comment: The *Shim.Drawing*  assembly that provides the `Systen.Drawing` subset for the Portable AForge and Accord projects is deliberately missing public `Bitmap` constructors. This is to enforce the user to create an initial image using the native image types (`WriteableBitmap` on WPF/UWP, `CGImage` on iOS, `Anroid.Graphics.Bitmap` on Android), that is explicitly cast to a `System.Drawing.Bitmap`, e.g. `var bitmap = (Bitmap)nativeImg`.

Comment: OK thanks (sorry for the late reply!) - I will have to work around it. I don't want to use the native types at this point as this is all processing that needs to be done in my PCL rather than in the platform specific code.